# Convergence in probability of product random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

If $Y_n$s converge to constant $c$ in probability & $(X_n)$ is a sequense of random variables, is it true that $X_nY_n- cX_n$ converge to $0$ in probability?

How can I prove this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Replace $Y_n$ by $Y_n-c$: you are reduced to the case $c=0$. Now, if $Y_n$ is constant equal to (say) $1/n$, and $X_n=n^2$, we will not have the wanted convergence. Of course, if $\sup_{\omega\in\Omega}\sup_n|X_n(\omega)|$ is finite, there will be no problem.

A sufficient condition for $X_nY_n\to 0$ in probability could be that for every fixed positive $\varepsilon$, one can find a constant $M=M(\varepsilon)$ such that for each $n$, $\mathbb P(|X_n|\gt M)\lt\varepsilon$. This is a little bit weaker than being bounded.

Comment: @ Davide Giraudo thank u , if i know that $X_n$ converges to random variable $X$ in distribution , is that claim true?

Comment: Yes, since it will satisfy the sufficient condition (it is tight).

Comment: @@ Davide Giraudo thank u a lot!how can i prove convergence to a random variable implies tightness?

Comment: Use the pointwise convergence of distribution function at a continuity point and sufficiently large.

Comment: @@ Davide Giraudo is it useful to note the relative compactness?